# Can uniqid() be the same for 2 concurrently executing scripts?

Tags: php

I am using the following code to save files on server:

```
<?php
$uuid = uniqid();
$uploaddir = getcwd();
$uploaddir = $uploaddir ."/files/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$uuid. basename($_FILES['image_file']['name']);
$relativePath = "files/".$uuid. basename($_FILES['image_file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo $relativePath;
} else {
   echo "Error";
}
?>
```

I am confused how PHP handles simultaneity.

Lets take this example. 2 users upload the file( with the same name )at exactly the same time and therefore PHP scrips should be executed at the same time.

I am aware that hundred of PHP scripts can run concurrently, but I am not aware if they can in such manner, that `uniqid()`, which is calculated from current time, is the same for both script executions. If uuid() can be the same, what prefix should I choose for file names?

Comment: why would there be more than one file of the same name? Why don't you just rename them at the time of upload? it's not like we're talking about 50 people at the same time and at the nearest millisecond.

Comment: For a unique image name, I usually do something like `md5(rand()*time());`. If it's the answer that interest you technically, run `echo uniqid(); echo uniqid();` to see if you get two different results

Comment: plus, checking to see if the file exists on top of what I said earlier

Comment: As I'm [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uniqid.php), you can add a prefix or increase entropy. `uniqid(md5(rand()));`

Comment: In 2017+ do `hash('sha512', random_bytes(64))`

Comment: _"Warning: This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value."_

Comment: Actually you got the file for entropy, use `sha1_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])`, who wants dupes..

Comment: Your concept `!=` your webserver's concept of "exactly the same time"

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

> This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to increase likelihood of uniqueness.

If, somehow, this happens at the same recorded microsecond in the system, it will be the same.

My go-to approach is to seed something that you know is unique into this kind of string. You can, for example, hash a primary key and a `uniqid` together. If you aren't worried about exposing your primary key, you can use something as simple as `md5` or even prefixing the ID. If you use `md5`, the resulting string will be longer than `uniqid`.

Another option is to generate a uniqid and insert it into a relational database with a unique constraint before writing to the file. If the insertion fails due to a unique constraint violation, you can embed it in a loop until successful.

```
<?php

/**
 * Generates a unique value to be used as a filename.
 * @return string
 */
function getUniqueId(): string
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO unique_filenames (value) VALUES (?)');
    // thanks to random_int, this should only need to happen once.
    // limit to 10 tries in order to avoid an infinite loop.
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        $unique = uniqid(random_int(1000,9999), true); // second value is more entropy
        try {
            $stmt->execute([$unique]);
            return $unique;
        } catch (\PDOException) {
            error_log('file collision. trying again.');
        }
    }

    throw new MyCustomException('Somehow failed to generate a unique ID');
}
```